# openshift: allow serviceaccount to create project

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools, openshift-3

i created a service account for gitlab `oc create serviceaccount gitlab-sa`

i assigned to this service account an edit role for the project and for the cluster

`oc policy add-role-to-user edit -z gitlab-sa`  and `oc policy add-cluster-role-to-user -z gitlab-sa`

i can successfully login using oc login *openshift-server* --token=*gitlab-sa-token*
but when i create a new project `oc new-project foo`

i get:  *Error from server (Forbidden): You may not request a new project via this API*

How can i allow this serviceaccount to create a new project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `oc policy add-cluster-role-to-user self-provisioner -z gitlab-sa`. Service accounts aren't able to create projects by default.

Answer (score 3):

The command

```
oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user self-provisioner -z [service-account-username] -n [namespace]
```

works for me.